# Issue with Lambda to sort a list

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, list, lambda

I'm using a custom List to store contacts:

```
    Dim Contacts As List(Of Contact) = New List(Of Contact)

    ' Create a new contact
    Dim CurrentContact As Contact = New Contact With { _
        .Name = "Manolo el del Bombo", _
        .Country = "Spain", _
        .City = "Valencia", _
        .Street = "Av. Mestalla", _
        .ZipCode = "42731", _
        .Phone = "96.XXX.XX.XX", _
        .CellPhone = "651.XXX.XXX", _
        .Email = "ManoloToLoko@Gmail.es"}

    ' Add a contact to contacts list
    Contacts.Add(CurrentContact)
```

Now what I want to do is to make a generic function to sort or reorder the contacts by a member variable and also specifying ascending or descending mode, I've tried to do this:

```
Private Function Sort_ContactList(ByVal ContactList As List(Of Contact), _
                                  ByVal Field As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of Object))) As List(Of Contact)

    Dim member As Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression = _
        If(TypeOf Field.Body Is Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression, _
        DirectCast(DirectCast(Field.Body, Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression).Operand, Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression), _
        DirectCast(Field.Body, Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression))

    ' MsgBox(OrderedContacts.First.Name & " " & OrderedContacts.First.Country)
    Return (From contact In ContactList Order By member Ascending Select contact).ToList()

End Function
```

And I call the function like this:

```
Contacts = Sort_ContactList(Contacts, Function() New Contact With {.Name = Nothing})
```

At this point I have two problems:

1. No idea of how to pass the Ascending/Descending keyword as an argument of the function to use it right.
2. The function will not sort the list, maybe the problem is in the Lambda expression that I'm using or my checks of Member Expressions because I'm not experienced with these things.

Someone can give me help?

UPDATE:

The Contact class contains those private members:

```
Private mId As System.Guid
Private mName As String
Private mCountry As String
Private mCity As String
Private mStreet As String
Private mZip As String
Private mPhone As String
Private mCellPhone As String
Private mEmail As String
```

..I think that means I can't pass a lambda like this:

```
Sort_ContactList(Contacts, Function() Contact.mName)
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: @Dominic Kexel thanks for comment but using whatever else (.Sort + Comparers, .Orderby + Thenby) I will get the same problem, sorting as normally is easy, but like I've said I need to make it generic the sorting in a function with the usage of lambda, and there is where is not easy for me.

Comment: `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` are generic and you can use lambda methods with them, so I still don't see the problem. Instead of `Sort_ContactList(Contacts, Function() Contact.Name)` why not just `Contacs.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name)`?

Comment: Problem 1: I *think* that is not required. I suppose that the `Ascending`/`Descending` keyword in your LINQ expression will automatically invoke something that inverts the sorted list, if required (`ascending` being assumed by default). Problem 2, clarification: To what extent is it possible to modify your `Contact` class? Usually, in such scenarios, things get much easier if the sorted class (`Contact` in this case) offers a way to return property values (suitable for sorting) by some identifier/index (that you pass to your `Field` parameter) rather than reflection-based approaches.

Comment: @Dominic Kexel oops, it's true, you've solved my problem, thankyou so much, I realize I did not think well on the problem and its solution, if you want to convert the comment to an answer I will mark it. PS: Forgive my english

Comment: @DominicKexel: If I understand the problem correctly, `OrderBy` *is* what he/she is doing (it gets called by the LINQ expression). He/she is trying to write the `Function(c) c.Name` part in a way to pass the property name by which sorting occurs as a function argument.

Comment: @ElektroHacker Convertet my comments to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)?

[`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) and [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) are generic and you can use lambda methods with them.

Instead of:

```
Sort_ContactList(Contacts, Function() Contact.Name)
```

simply use:

```
Contacs.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name)
```